# How to map gherkin step definition data to a Java object in Cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have following three classes:

```
class City {
 String name;
 String code;
}

class Address {
 String street;
 City city;
}

class Person {
 String name;
 int age;
 Address address;
}
```

Now, I have a REST API to POST a person.

```
POST /person

{
 "name":"John",
 "age":21,
 "address":{
  "street":"First st.",
  "city":{
   "name":"London"
  }
 }
}
```

To test this API, I created a scenario using Cucumber and within that created following step definition:

```
Then a person is created using REST api "/person"
| name | age | address.street | address.city.name |
| John | 21  | First st.      | London            |
```

In my Java class, created following method to map this step onto it:

```
public void create_a_person(Person person){
 System.out.println("Person - " + person);
}
```

This code is unable to create a person object using the data given in the step. It throws following exception:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type: class Person
```

However, it easily creates Person object, if data is given like:

```
Then a person is created using REST api "/person"
| name | age |
| John | 21  |
```

Any idea, how can Cucumber map step data onto child member variables (like Address and City in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find your answer here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable#custom-table-types.
You'll need to implement a TableTransformer.

Tables are a bit of an 'odd' data type in cucumber, e.g. compared to [other +custom data types, that live in cucumber expressions](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#custom-parameter-types)

Comment: Please avoid link-based answers when the link expires your useful answer becomes useless.